# Time complexity of remove vertex method in an adjacency list implementation of a graph

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graph, big-o, adjacency-list

I am trying to implement a graph data structure using an adjacency list (with a hash map container). I understand there are multiple ways to implement this with different data structures, but I just wanted to separate GraphVertex class and Graph class to maybe be able to easily transform it later into a weighted graph and/or even a directed graph. Code below:

```
class GraphVertex {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.edges = {};
  }
}

class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.vertices = {};
  }

  // O(1)
  addVertex(vertex) {
    if (!this.vertices[vertex]) this.vertices[vertex] = new GraphVertex(vertex);
  }

  // O(1)
  addEdge(vertexOne, vertexTwo) {
    this.vertices[vertexOne].edges[vertexTwo] = true;
    this.vertices[vertexTwo].edges[vertexOne] = true;
  }

  // O(V) ???
  removeVertex(targetVertex) {
    delete this.vertices[targetVertex];
    const verticesArr = Object.keys(this.vertices);
    for (let i = 0; i < verticesArr.length; i++) {
      const vertex = verticesArr[i];
      if (this.vertices[vertex].edges[targetVertex]) {
        delete this.vertices[vertex].edges[targetVertex];
      }
    }
  }

  // O(1)
  removeEdge(vertexOne, vertexTwo) {
    delete this.vertices[vertexOne].edges[vertexTwo];
    delete this.vertices[vertexTwo].edges[vertexOne];
  }
}
```

And I was trying to understand the time complexities of some of the methods. I keep reading that remove vertex for a list would be O(V + E) however then I read that if you use a hash table it could be O(E). But looking at my code it seems the time complexity is actually O(V). Am I interpreting the Big-O of my code correctly? Or did I even write the method correctly?

Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the list of vertices in `removeVertex` function so the complexity is O(V) (it growths linearly with vertices number).